# Does Object_ID Change for Stored Procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to create a reference to a stored procedure that will not break when the procedure changes? I was considering storing the procedure's Object_ID, but my report configurations will break if the ID changes. Tables sometimes receive new IDs when changes cause them to be deleted/re-created. Are there any similar scenarios when dealing with stored procedures?

Comment: There shouldn't be changes to `object_id` to the stored procedures, try it by testing `select * from sys.procedures`

Comment: What's wrong with referring to the procedure by name?

Comment: If you delete and recreate proc it would change `object_id`, modifying or alter should not change Object_id

Comment: +1 @TabAlleman I work with an environment that also refers to Stored Procedures and Indexes by name in reference tables.  Is this a problem for what you're trying to do?

Comment: @TabAlleman I considered that but there will be multiple users and I don't want anything to disconnect if they do change the name. We have 100's of output procedures for our reports

Comment: @BHouse I did do a few of my own tests and Object_ID seemed to work. I am just wondering if there are other considerations such as backup/restore, SQL Update, schema change, etc. that might cause me issues.

Comment: @TabAlleman In my tests I was able to change the name with no consequences

Comment: How, by renaming in the GUI?   I can't imagine a world where you're more concerned about keeping the Object_ID of a stored procedure than the name.   Change the name and every bit of code you have that does `EXECUTE MyStoredProc` will break.   What if your developers change the name by creating a new stored proc with the new name and dropping the stored proc with the old name?

Comment: @TabAlleman GUI and sp_rename both work without consequence. I am considering Object_ID for the exact reason you just mentioned. I am not concerned about NEW procedures.

Comment: Ok, but like I said, I can't imagine your world.  I have never once used the GUI or sp_rename to change the name of a stored procedure.  If my boss told me to rename a stored procedure, I would do it by changing the name in the CREATE PROCEDURE script, executing the CREATE PROCEDURE script, and then dropping the old one.   If you're sure you don't have to worry about anybody doing that, then good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165932/discussion-between-brandon-church-and-tab-alleman).